# how can I use aggregate() in R to work out this mean?

Tags: r, aggregate, mean

Use the aggregate() command to calculate the proportion of trips that occurred on the weekend among subscribers vs. non-subscribers. Provide a clear interpretation of the numbers you see, and answer whether there appears to be a difference in bike usage on weekdays vs. weekends among subscribers vs. non-subscribers?

My code is like this:

aggregate(is_weekend ~ is_subscriber , data = citibike, FUN=mean)

Comment: Please provide the `dput` of your data in your question so it is easier for others to help. For example, if you run `dput(citibike)` and paste the output into this question, we can help a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what your data looks like, but it seems you're missing your y (response) variable. As I read it, `is_weekend` and `is_subscriber` are your categorical variables indicating the group they are in (subscriber vs. non-subscriber etc.) You need to include your response variable (bike usage). This is what you should do to answer you question:

```
means <- aggregate(citibike$Y_VAR , by=list(citibike$is_subscriber, citibike$is_weekend), mean) 
means
```

Hope this helps.